# Unable to install scala

Tags: scala, ubuntu

I just want to install Scala in my Ubuntu. I followed these methods:

1. I downloaded binary files from http://www.scala-lang.org/download/2.10.6.html (scala-2.10.6.tgz)
2. I unzipped this tar ball in my home location
3. Set environment like this /.bashrc file

---

```
export SCALA_HOME="/home/beeshma/scala-2.10.6"

set PATH="$PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin"

export PATH
```

But when I checked with `version` within the command prompt:

```
beeshma@ubuntu:~$ scala -version

The program 'scala' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install scala
```

So am I missing anything ?

Comment: Do you have the JRE installed on your machine?

Comment: I guess it's only a typo here, anyway - it should be ~/.bashrc not /.bashrc (so .bashrc in your home directory, not .bashrc in the root of file system)

Comment: what's `set`? you don't need `set PATH=` just `PATH=`.

Comment: It's likely the PATH variable is not being set correctly, see this [cool post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26059) on the question, which includes some important caveats. For example, you cannot use `~/.bashrc` if you're not using bash, so it's better to set the PATH in `~/.profile`. In any case, why are you not using `apt-get` to install scala? Do you specifically need the version in the question (2.10.6)?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the word `set` in line **set PATH="$PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin"**. It will work fine. The syntax for set in bash shell is not the one expected in the code listed, it is for some other shell.

Try any of the following codes:

```
export SCALA_HOME="/home/beeshma/scala-2.10.6"
PATH="$PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin"

export PATH
```

(or)

```
 export SCALA_HOME="/home/beeshma/scala-2.10.6"
 export PATH="$PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin"
```

In your case change to variable `PATH` did not happen as you tried to do with 'set' in bash shell. Hence when you export the `PATH` the original unchanged `PATH` is still retained and exported.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like it should work (assuming you use bash) but just to confirm:

At end of ~/.bashrc file

```
SCALA_HOME="/home/beeshma/scala-2.10.6"
export PATH="$SCALA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

After you save the file, remember to run.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Also double check that you aren't overwriting your PATH variable later on.

Also, please confirm that you are editing ~/.bashrc (versus /.bashrc). I'm sure you already know this, but ~ refers to $HOME, which is where you should edit the .bashrc file.